# Where best to create your objects?

Tags: c#

Say I'm iterating through a list or a data reader with

```
foreach(var v in _list)
{
    ....stuff
}
```

or

```
while(_reader.Read())
{
    ....stuff
}
```

and I want to create a new instance of object for use only in each iteration (eg an object which has to be populated with values from the list or reader on each iteration), should I create the object before entering the loop and assign values etc, then null the object before the next iteration, or create a new object on each iteration?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the compiler will optimize it away most likely.

Comment: If you're not using the object(s) outside the loop, then do it inside. It's better to have the code be "scope safe."

Comment: After doing some testing, if you're worried about performance, if there is a difference between the two styles it is so minute that one shouldn't be concerned about it. It all comes down to what's the best practice for respecting scope.

Comment: Thanks, to put into context it's for a Windows service which will run once a day and that particular loop will run at most a couple of thousand times

Comment: There's no good reason to explicitly assign null to the variable in the loop, regardless of which option you choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> should I create the object before entering the loop and assign values etc, then null the object before the next iteration, or create a new object on each iteration?

If the object is only needed within the loop body, create it in the scope of the loop body.  There is no need to declare an object outside the scope it is referenced.  The garbage collector is quite efficient dealing with such objects.

There is no need to null anything out.

Comment: thanks, that's how I have it anyway, but was concerned about possible issues arising from creating thousands of objects per list / read

Answer (score 2):

I would personally allocate a new object on each iteration. I doubt the approaches would result in different IL because based purely on my observations you will end up reusing the same block of memory either way and all that's effectively happening is all the bits are being set to 0 each iteration. So for the sake of clean code I'd just write;

```
foreach(var v in _list)
{
    MyReferenceType temp = new MyReferenceType();
    // do stuff with temp object
    // object goes out of scope here and same memory will be reused
    // when we get back to the first statement in the loop
}
```